# _tkinter.TclError: Item {...} not found

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter, treeview

I'm trying to build a python program that has excel features. After following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bn1n1diGv_0&list=PLCC34OHNcOtoC6GglhF3ncJ5rLwQrLGnV&index=125&ab_channel=Codemy.com) for opening a excel spreadsheet in Treeview using Tkinter, i tried to make a function to delete columns after you name it in a entry widget. But it has returned this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: Item {'width': 200, 'minwidth': 20, 'stretch': 1, 'anchor': 'w', 'id': 'Sit Sin'} not found
```

("Sit Sin" is the name of a column in a spreadsheet i'm using)

This is the code for opening the excel file + the function for deleting columns

```
def clear_tree():
    Ttree.delete(*Ttree.get_children())

def open_file():
    namefile= filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="C:",
        title="Open a File",
        filetype=(("xlsx files", "*.xlsx"), ("All files", "*.*"))
    )
    namefile= r"{}".format(namefile)
    df = pd.read_excel(namefile)

    # clears the treeview
    clear_tree()
    # Set up new tree
    Ttree['column'] = list(df.columns)
    Ttree['show'] = "headings"
    # loop in the column list
    for column in Ttree['column']:
        Ttree.heading(column, text=column)
    # putting data in the treeview
    df_columns = df.to_numpy().tolist()
    # loop the data and putting them on the screen
    for row in df_columns:
        Ttree.insert("", "end", values=row)

def drop_columns():
    namecolumn = entry_name_column.get()
    var = Ttree.column(namecolumn)
    Ttree.delete(var)
```

What I am doing wrong ? Is deleting columns only doable with Pandas or Xlwings ?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Do you know what `namecolumn` and `var` is when you run the code?

Comment: `Ttree.delete()` is used to delete rows, not columns.  You need to go through all the rows to remove the specified column.

Comment: When I run the code with Shift+F9, in pycharm, it just goes normal, this isn't what you meant right ? I'm very new to python and programming in general, so any help with the debugging is welcome.

Comment: `@acw1668`   So deleting every row will automatically remove the column ? There is a specific way to remove the column ?

Comment: You need to remove the column from `Ttree['columns']` and the corresponding cell in every row using `values` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `Ttree.column(namecolumn)` returns a dictionary of the options of the given column name.  `Ttree.delete()` is used to delete row, not column.

`Treeview` does not have function to delete a column, so you need to:

- remove the heading from 'columns' option
- remove the *corresponding column* from every row

Below is the modified `drop_columns()`:

```py
def drop_columns():
    namecolumn = entry_name_column.get().strip()
    columns = list(Ttree['columns'])
    try:
        # get the index of the column, exception when column cannot be found
        idx = columns.index(namecolumn)
        # remove the column heading
        columns.pop(idx)
        Ttree['columns'] = columns
        for col in columns:
            Ttree.heading(col, text=col)
        # remove the corresponding column from all rows
        for row in Ttree.get_children():
            values = list(Ttree.item(row, 'values'))
            values.pop(idx)
            Ttree.item(row, values=values)
    except ValueError as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It's perfect ! Also, thanks for explaining what i was doing wrong. Much obliged.